# spring mvc +hibernate one to many delete option

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

i am working on spring mvc but i am facing this problem

```
 Provided id of the wrong type. Expected: class java.lang.Long, got class java.lang.Integer
```

here is my dao code

```
@Override
    public String delete(long  id) {

        /*sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM Invoice WHERE id = "+ id).executeUpdate();*/
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM InvoiceBatch WHERE id = "+ id).executeUpdate();
        return "Successfuly Deleted";
    }
```

here is my contoller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/delete",method=RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView deleteEmployee( @RequestParam("id") String id, ModelMap model)
     {
       Long eid =Long.parseLong(id);
       model.put("message",invoicManager.delete(eid));
       //model.put("", invoicManager.clientList());

       return new ModelAndView("Invoices", model);
      }
```

here is my pojo

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="BATCH_REFERE
```

am i missing something

kindly help

Comment: Please specify where exactly on which like in you code are you getting that error.

Comment: do you think about to use `Criteria Hibernate`? i think that can help you to handle data type

Comment: I can see how you are using different long types, while in your service delete method is **long** , in your controller you are sending a **Long** type.